# Identifying fantasy story about a knight in another world

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

A knight wakes on a hill surrounded by the detritus of battle. He walks to a nearby city, where he finds employment selling 'hands of glory' in the market. A horribly scarred and mad princess meets him there. Eventually they are married and he must go on a quest to cure her.

He meets the dog-person who maimed her, is turned into a stag, and at the conclusion of the book is sent back to his own time and place, a battle in Scotland where he is fighting his greatest enemy.

I believe it was a trilogy of novels. These are just the points that stand out vividly that I can be sure were from the same series- I read the books about 6 or 7 years ago (2007-2008) so it's all quite blurred

Comment: You say "story", but was it a full novel? A comic?

Comment: I believe it was a trilogy of novels. These are just the points that stand out vividly that I can be sure were from the same series- I read the books about 6 or 7 years ago so it's all quite blurred.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189324/help-finding-fantasy-book-detailed-description-below (which is newer but has an OP comment indicating the answer is correct)

Answer (score 7):

"The Red Pavillions" series by Kim Hunter. The first book is: "Knight's Dawn":

> A wounded soldier comes to consciousness on a hillside above a forest.
>   His helmet and sword are gone, but he still wears the bloodstained
>   remnants of his armour, on which the words 'Kutrama and Sintra' are
>   printed. The soldier looks about in astonishment - he has no idea how
>   he got there or who he is. He believes he has been in a mighty battle,
>   but as to the cause or outcome he has no idea. Only later does he
>   learn that the last battle in that kingdom was over a century ago ...
>
> Soldier comes to the city of Zamerkand and finds himself caught up in
>   its vicious politics and mad economic structure; hired to collect
>   severed hands from the many hanged, his death is ordered by
>   politicians who just don't want any unaccountable players in town and
>   reprieved by a mad and disfigured princess, with whom he falls
>   desperately in love. On a quest to find the cure for her madness, he
>   finds himself endlessly caught in mythic patterns that go otherwise
>   than we expect...

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Knights-Dawn-Red-Pavilions-Book/dp/1841490318