# Fantasy trilogy about an amnesiac man greeting by a talking crow, who marries a psychopathic princess

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a trilogy about 10 years ago, and I can remember a lot of the plot, but have no idea the name of the book or the author, so any help would be appreciated. The plot from what I believe is the first book is below:

It starts with a man who wakes up with no memory of who he is or where he is from. I believe there is a talking crow there to greet him too.

He goes to a city and gets in a fight, and so he is put to death, but a princess says that she will marry him to save him. She has scars on her face and also turns into a psychopath and tries to kill him regularly due to a madness she gets.

He gets sent beyond the walls to help against an attack from some tribesmen who wear human skin as a way to show their kills. He does well in battle.

He gets sent on a quest to try and fix his wife's madness, although I can't think of the details. He completes this task and says that he wishes that his wife has what she wants most taken away but when he gets back she is still mad but her scars are gone.

I think his name is "Soldier".

I tried so hard to find this but haven't had any luck! I remember that the books looked old when I got them.

Comment: Are you sure her name wasn't soldier? - *"Eight years ago, Emmie Silvey was born on Halloween during a full moon. Raised in Providence by her widower father, she's a strange, yellow-eyed girl, plagued with visions of impossible worlds and fabulous beings. Inextricably linked with a violent young woman named Soldier, together they must face the monsters and unearthly forces that have shaped their lives...and threaten their futures."* - https://www.amazon.co.uk/Daughter-Hounds-Kiernan/dp/0451461576

Answer (score 8):

Red Pavillions series by Kim Hunter

Synopsis for the first book [Knight's Dawn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EORABA4):

> **A SOLDIER WITHOUT A PAST**
>
> A wounded knight awakens alone on a hillside. His only memory is that
>   of a mighty battle - but there has not been a battle in this place for
>   more than a hundred years.
>
> Tired, hungry and alone, the knight must rely on the help of others if
>   he is to survive. Kindness takes him to the magnificent city of
>   Zamerkand, but what lies inside the city gates will leave his life in
>   more danger than ever.
>
> Safety can only be found in the ranks of the mercenary army known as
>   the Red Pavilions. But joining up is only the beginning of an
>   extraordinary quest for the man who calls himself Soldier - a quest
>   for revenge, for truth and for his own identity.

Comment: Yes it's Knight's Dawn I'm sure of it after reading some of the reviews! Thank you so much!

Comment: @CharCharLee If this answer is correct, use the green tick next to the answer to indicate that ;-)